# "СообщениЙ" вместо "СообщениЯ" в блоке по статистике сообщений пользователя

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, локализация

На странице профиля пользователя в блоках со статистикой по *количеству* сообщений, слово "сообщения" необходимо заменить на "сообщений". По проценту же сообщений, слово написано верно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё сложнее: 21 сообщение, 22 сообщения, 25 сообщений.

Comment: @VladD, не совсем так. Слово "сообщений" в данном блоке стоит перед числом, т.е. будет: сообщений 21, сообщений 22, сообщений 25.

Comment: По-моему, там ещё двоеточия не хватает: `СООБЩЕНИЙ: 11`, формы слова в этом случае хватит и одной.

Comment: Вроде нормально в именительном падеже. "Рейтинг" на "рейтинга" менять ведь никто не собирается.